# the app falls when i select a user from a SQLITE list and pass the ID to another activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-listview, android-sqlite

i have a minor problem here, the app i created makes the user adds contacts details of his own and can call them again by pressing on them from the listview and thier data should appear on the new activity to edit or delete them

the problem is that the app crashes when i select a contact....where did i go wrong??

the MainActivity.java:

package com.hossa.contactsapp;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button ADD;
ListView LS;
DBcreator dbview;
SQLiteDatabase db;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();// define
                                                                                    // an
                                                                                    // arraylist
                                                                                    // with
                                                                                    // hashmap
                                                                                    // for
                                                                                    // ref.//

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ADD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
    LS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ContactsList);
    /*
     * SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, List,
     * R.layout.activity_main, new String[] { DBcreator.KEY_ROWID,
     * DBcreator.KEY_FNAME, DBcreator.KEY_LNAME, DBcreator.KEY_MOBILE,
     * DBcreator.KEY_ADDRESS }, new int[] { R.id.ContactsList });
     * 
     * LS.setAdapter(sa);
     */
    existingcontacts();
    LS.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // what happens when you select a contact
            Intent j = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditContact.class);
            j.putExtra("ID", id);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });

    ADD.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateContact.class);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });
}

private void existingcontacts() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBcreator db = new DBcreator(MainActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor find = database.rawQuery("select * from contactsdisplay", null);// go
                                                                            // read
                                                                            // from
                                                                            // the
                                                                            // database
                                                                            // contactsdisplay//
    // below is the adapter to put the intended content in the list view//
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.listviewdistribution, find, new String[] {
                    DBcreator.KEY_FNAME, DBcreator.KEY_LNAME,
                    DBcreator.KEY_MOBILE, DBcreator.KEY_ADDRESS },
            new int[] { R.id.FirstNameTextView, R.id.LastNameTextView,
                    R.id.MobileTextView, R.id.AddressTextView });
    // below is looping with the cursor inside the table to get all data//
    while (find.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("_ID", find.getString(0));
        data.put("FirstName", find.getString(1));
        data.put("LastName", find.getString(2));
        data.put("Mobile", find.getString(3));
        data.put("Address", find.getString(4));
        List.add(data);
    }
    LS.setAdapter(cursor);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

the EditContact.java:

```
public class EditContact extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button SaveEdit, Cancel, Delete;
TextView fname2, lname2, mobile2, address2;
EditText editfirst2, editlast2, editmobile2, editaddress2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editcontact);

    Intent i = new Intent();
    final int getid = i.getIntExtra("ID", -1);
    DBcreator db = new DBcreator(this);
    SQLiteDatabase getdata = db.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = getdata.rawQuery("select * from " + DBcreator.DATABASE_TABLE
            + "WHERE id = " + getid, null);
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                editfirst2.setText(c.getString(0));
                editlast2.setText(c.getString(1));
                editmobile2.setText(c.getString(3));
                editaddress2.setText(c.getString(4));

            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }

    }
    SaveEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveChanges);
    Cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);
    Delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DeleteContact);
    fname2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FirstNametv2);
    lname2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LastNametv2);
    mobile2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Mobiletv2);
    address2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Addresstv2);
    editfirst2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ViewFirstName);
    editlast2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ViewLastName);
    editmobile2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ViewMobile);
    editaddress2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ViewAddress);

    SaveEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
    Cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    Delete.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.SaveChanges:
        DBcreator edit = new DBcreator(EditContact.this);
        String fname = editfirst2.getEditableText().toString();
        String lname = editlast2.getEditableText().toString();
        String mob = editmobile2.getEditableText().toString();
        String address = editaddress2.getEditableText().toString();
        edit.open();
        edit.savechanges(fname, lname, mob, address);
        edit.close();
        Intent y = new Intent(EditContact.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(y);
        break;
    case R.id.CancelButton:
        Intent k = new Intent(EditContact.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(k);
        break;
    case R.id.DeleteContact:
        DBcreator delete = new DBcreator(EditContact.this);
        String fnamedelete = editfirst2.getEditableText().toString();
        String lnamedelete = editlast2.getEditableText().toString();
        String mobdelete = editmobile2.getEditableText().toString();
        String addressdelete = editaddress2.getEditableText().toString();
        delete.open();
        delete.deletecontact(fnamedelete);
        delete.close();
        Intent h = new Intent(EditContact.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(h);
        break;
    }
}

}
```

the LOGCAT:

```
01-08 16:57:24.718: E/Trace(19947): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-08 16:57:25.121: W/MMUMapper(19947): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-08 16:57:25.633: W/MMUMapper(19947): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-08 16:57:25.802: W/MMUMapper(19947): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-08 16:57:26.272: I/SurfaceTextureClient(19947): [0x51770780] frames:12, duration:1.011000, fps:11.866401
01-08 16:57:29.258: W/MMUMapper(19947): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x528b8000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-08 16:57:29.259: W/MMUMapper(19947): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52e65000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-08 16:57:29.260: W/MMUMapper(19947): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52b5f000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-08 16:57:29.559: W/MMUMapper(19947): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-08 16:57:29.757: W/MMUMapper(19947): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-08 16:57:29.963: W/MMUMapper(19947): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-08 16:57:31.545: W/MMUMapper(19947): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52d5f000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-08 16:57:31.547: W/MMUMapper(19947): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52e65000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-08 16:57:31.555: W/MMUMapper(19947): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x53011000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-08 16:57:31.975: W/MMUMapper(19947): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-08 16:57:32.158: W/MMUMapper(19947): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-08 16:57:32.654: W/MMUMapper(19947): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-08 16:57:33.155: I/SurfaceTextureClient(19947): [0x528afd98] frames:5, duration:1.013000, fps:4.931273
01-08 16:57:35.315: I/SurfaceTextureClient(19947): [0x528afd98] frames:10, duration:2.188000, fps:4.570112
01-08 16:57:36.200: I/AbsListView(19947): Fling from scroll with initialVelocity = -160,mActivePointerId = 0,mFirstPosition = 1,firstChildTop = -36,this = android.widget.ListView@415fd8a8
01-08 16:57:36.325: I/SurfaceTextureClient(19947): [0x528afd98] frames:57, duration:1.010000, fps:56.415134
01-08 16:57:37.043: E/SQLiteLog(19947): (1) near "=": syntax error
01-08 16:57:37.043: W/dalvikvm(19947): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f4e908)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hossa.contactsapp/com.hossa.contactsapp.EditContact}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from contactsdisplayWHERE id = -1
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2203)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5006)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from contactsdisplayWHERE id = -1
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at com.hossa.contactsapp.EditContact.onCreate(EditContact.java:29)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5076)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2167)
01-08 16:57:37.063: E/AndroidRuntime(19947):    ... 11 more
01-08 16:57:39.693: I/Process(19947): Sending signal. PID: 19947 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:
select * from contactsdisplayWHERE id = -1
```

you need space between table name and `WHERE`:

```
select * from contactsdisplay WHERE id = -1
```

Comment: 01-08 17:11:44.986: E/AndroidRuntime(20823): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id (code 1): , while compiling: select * from contactsdisplay WHERE id = -1

Comment: This data.put("_ID", find.getString(0)) says that your column name is _ID, column id doesn't exists.

Comment: @El_Mochiq thx but this section is working fine , the one not working when i choose a user from those displayed in the list